# Angular 7 dynamic columns with function calls

Tags: angular

I've got a table with dynamic columns (as per example from here - https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5927):

```
<!-- Generic column definition -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [cdkColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ column.header }}</md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ column.cell(row) }}</md-cell>
</ng-container>

columns = [
  { columnDef: 'userId',    header: 'ID',       cell: (row: UserData) => `${row.id}`        },
  { columnDef: 'userName',  header: 'Name',     cell: (row: UserData) => `${row.name}`      },
  { columnDef: 'progress',  header: 'Progress', cell: (row: UserData) => `${row.progress}%` }
];

displayedColumns = this.columns.map(x => x.columnDef);
```

This is working as expected with object values.

I've got a departmentId property in the object and I would like to load the department title, so I tried the following:

```
columns = [
  { columnDef: 'userId',     header: 'ID',         cell: (row: UserData) => `${row.id}`        },
  { columnDef: 'userName',   header: 'Name',       cell: (row: UserData) => `${row.name}`      },
  { columnDef: 'department', header: 'Department', cell: (row: UserData) => `${this.getDepartmentName(row.departmentId)}` }
];
```

but the function never gets called. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong and how to approach this in a proper way? I've got all the department values loaded before initiating the columns variable.

Edit:

Currently I am working around this is the following way:

```
forkJoin(
      this.settingsService.getDepartments(),
      this.settingsService.getEmployees()
    ).subscribe(([departments, employees]) => {
      this.departments = departments;
      this.employees = employees;

      this.employees.forEach(e => {
        e.department = this.getDepartmentName(e.departmentId);
      });

      this.dataSource.data = employees;
```

Then I am can use `row.department` in the `columns`, but I don't think it's the correct approach.

Comment: Is getDepartmentName sync, or async?

Comment: It is sync, and all departments are available before `columns` are initiated. Currently my workaround is to have a string Department property for each user, that gets assigned when Users are loaded, but I recon this is not the right way.

Comment: Then the only other thing that I can think of is the `this` binding. The `<md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ column.cell(row) }}</md-cell>` gets extrapolated into... `<md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ `${this.getDepartmentName(row.departmentId)}`  }}</md-cell>`, I guess? OK, that construction looks a little complex to debug. I personally would move the function call from the template to the controller, and feed the template already computed values.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on stackblitz? I see it works here well https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta11-kzqhj4?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui, well, I'll be damned. I just noticed that I have been using `row[column.columnDef]` in my `mat-cell` definition instead of `column.cell(row)`. Thank you, both, for taking time to reply to this.

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted.it out